# How to hide home folder name from integrated VSCode's Terminal?

Tags: user-interface, terminal, visual-studio-code, user-experience

How to hide home folder name from integrated VSCode's Terminal?

Standard:

```
Andreys-MacBook-Pro:~ andreymarchenko$
```

I want to achieve:

```
~ $
```

Answer (score 2):

The VSCode app uses the default system terminal and your installed shell. In your case, it looks like a Mac so it is likely to be Terminal.app and bash(default).

You need to edit your `./.bash_profile` or `./.bashrc`  Or `/etc/bashrc` and change the settings for `PS1` to

```
PS1='\W\$'
```

and restart vscode.
However, this will change your default prompt either for your user or system level based on which file is changed.

Check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224149/show-username-on-mac-terminal-prompt